# How to create Recovery partition for mirroring Windows Server 2016 UEFI boot partitions?

Tags: boot, mirroring, windows-server-2016

I'm trying to follow [these instructions](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Mirroring_Windows_Server_2008_GBT_and_MBR_Boot_and_System_Disks) based on Windows Server 2008, but some things seem to have changed in 2016 - namely the `Recovery` partition seems to be an addition I don't know how to handle.

I have two identical 4TB drives. I have a successful Windows Server 2016 installation on Disk 1 booting UEFI.

I have cleaned and converted Disk 0 in preparation for mirroring Disk 1. After running the `convert GPT` command the `Reserved` partition was automatically created. This is not accounted for in my instructions, but it seems to match the one on Disk 1, so I guess that's good.

Now I am trying to figure out how to create the `Recovery` partition since it's next in line on Disk 1. How should I proceed? My end goal is to convert both disks to dynamic RAID mirror so I can boot from the failover partition if need be. Thanks for your time.

[image: screenshot of partitions]

Comment: You do understand that the Recovery partition only contains WinRE, right?   So you only need a single instance of that partition.  "My end goal is to convert both disks to dynamic RAID mirror so I can boot from the failover partition if need be." - What your attempting to do right now won't lead you to that conclusion though.

Comment: @ramhound thanks for your input. Could you recommend an approach to accomplish that conclusion?

Comment: The tutorial you linked to is simply going to configure mirror drives it won't be a RAID array. So what do you actually want?  Do you want a HDD to fail, remove and replace, and the array rebuild or do this process each time you have a HDD failure?

Comment: @ramhound well I previously followed the section relating to MBR on a Windows server 2012R2 with two 1TB disks. When I booted, it was duplex, so I could choose either, but it didn't matter because they were identical. Then one hard drive failed, but it was ok because I could still boot into the other and had access to all my files. I replaced the failed drive, went through process again and it worked like a charm. Always had redundant coverage to prevent file loss. I want to do that again, but due to size must use GPT not MBR. Does that clarify my goals? Thanks for your help

Comment: Jeff - Please look at the section from that link you provided for the detail and follow the steps as outlined in the **"Mirroring Boot and System Volumes on a GPT Disk"** section. You should be able to get it to work just fine. I too have had to configure Windows OS level disk mirroring configurations with Servers that don't have RAID controllers to do it otherwise. I think you're just missing some of the steps and yes it'd likely be using GPT. Be sure you have good backups as well since redundancy alone is not a good backup strategy.

Answer (score -1):

run cmd as administrator run diskpart

first get info on the original and assign it letter Q

select disk 1

select partition 1

detail partition
(note down /copy the size and the id)

assign letter=Q

now make the copy and assign letter R

select disk 0

convert gpt

select partition 1

delete partition overrirde

create partition primary size=450 ( that's what you noted down before)

format fs=ntfs quick label=Recovery

set id=***** ( whatever you noted down)

assign letter=R

exit

use robocopy to move the data form Q to R

robocopy.exe q:\ r:\ * /e /copyall /dcopy:t /xd "System Volume Information"

That's the recovery partition done now for EFI

get the info on the original system and Reserve partitions this time you only need the sizes and assign letter S to the system

select disk 1

list partition

**noted down sizes of System( I think yours is 100MB) and reverse (normally 16MB)

selection partition 2

assign letter=S

make the copies give efi letter T

select disk 0

create partition efi size=100

format fs=fat32 quick

assign letter=t

create partition msr size=16

exit

robocopy.exe s:\ t:\ * /e /copyall /dcopy:t /xf BCD.* /xd "System Volume Information"

then mirror the c drive using the GUI

hope this helps

Comment: You could have just as well provide a link to the original article, so much nicer to read...
https://www.wintips.org/how-to-mirror-boot-hard-drive-on-windows-10-legacy-or-uefi/